# How to Sample from Frobenius Eigenspace?

Tags: elliptic-curves, isogeny

So I was implementing the $2$-point method described here[1], which requires to samples two points $P_0, P_1$ in the Frobenius eigenspace initially. It uses a method called *Elligator,* which seems to me only samples $\mathbb F_p$ rational points.

Suppose one is given a supersingular curve $E$ defined over $\mathbb F_p$ with Elkies prime $\ell$. Since the $\ell$-torsion $E[\ell]$ is a $\mathbb F_\ell$-linear space of rank 2 and the Frobenius mapping $\pi$ is linear. Let $\lambda$ be one of the eigenvalue in $\mathbb F_\ell$. How would one sample from its corresponding eigenspace $E[\pi-\lambda]$?

For $\lambda=1$ we simply take $\mathbb F_p$-rational points, but what about cases where $\lambda \neq 1$, say $\lambda=-1$?

[1]"A Faster Constant-time Algorithm of CSIDH keeping Two Points," page 10, Algorithm 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Frobenius eigenspace of $-1$ is, by definition, the kernel of the map $π+1$. Typically, this is further restricted to some torsion group $E[ℓ]$, so we are really talking about $E[ℓ] ∩ E[π+1]$, i.e., those points of $E[ℓ]$ such that $π(P)=-P$.

If the curve is expressed in Weierstrass form $y^2=f(x)$ (or Montgomery, or similar), letting $P=(x,y)$ we have $-P=(x,-y)$. Thus the Frobenius eigenspace is made by those points $(x,y)$ such that $x^p=x$ and $y^p=-y$.  A little theory shows that this is the set of rational points of the *twist* of $E/_p$.

So, the obvious way to sample the points is to

1. Choose a random $x\in _p$;
2. Check that $f(x)$ is **not** a square, i.e., that $y=\sqrt{f(x)}$ is not in $_p$, i.e., that $y^p=\sqrt{f(x)}f(x)^{(p-1)/2}=-\sqrt{f(x)}=-y$;¹
3. See $(x,y)$ as a point in $E/_{p^2}$, multiply by an *appropriate cofactor* to obtain a point in $E[ℓ]$.

¹To see why this works, note that $f(x)$ is not a square in $_p$, thus its Legendre symbol is $-1$. By the way, saying $x$ is in $_p$ and $y$ is not is equivalent to saying that $x$ is the abscissa of a rational point on the twist.

If $\#E(_p)=p+1-t$, where $t$ is the trace of $π$, then the twist has order $p+1+t$, thus the "appropriate cofactor" above is $(p+1+t)/ℓ$. Note that $E[π+1]∩E[π-1]=E[2]$ (because $1=-1\mod 2$), thus for $ℓ=2$ the two ℓ-restricted eigenspaces are indistinguishable, and you would get a random point of order $2$; however for any other prime $ℓ$ there are two distinct eigenspaces, and step 3. will stay in the twist.

Steps 1. and 2. above can be replaced by Elligator 2, which samples *simultaneously* in both the eigenspace of $+1$ and that of $-1$. The original Elligator 2 was explained as a map to $E[π-1]$, but the generalization to a map to $E[π-1]×E[π+1]$ is easy and has been hinted at in several papers. For an explicit description, see Section 3, and Algorithm 3 in particular, here: https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/837.

All this can be generalized to arbitrary eigenvalues $λ$, not just $±1$. The multiplicative order of $λ$ in $ℤ/ℓℤ$ determines the degree of the extension of $_p$ where the points $E[π-λ]$ are defined.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! But I am confused at the following. How do we make sure the obtained point $(x,y)\in E(\mathbb F_{p^2})$, after multiplying an appropriate co-factor, would be sitting in $E[\pi\pm 1]$ instead of their linear combination?

Comment: Also, by the appropriate co-factor is it simply $(p+1)^2/\ell$?

Comment: I edited the answer to address your questions. Hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: Perhaps I got this wrong. Did you mean that up to the isomorphism between curve and its twist $\iota: E\to E'$, $E[\pi+1]$ is exactly $E'(\mathbb F_p)$? In another word, $\iota(E[\pi+1])= E'(\mathbb F_p)$? Would you mind recommend some reference for "a little theory" mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, you got it exactly right. As for the theory, these are mostly simple consequences of the general principles you can find in any introductory book on e.c., such as Silverman, Milne, etc. I can't think of any reference specifically dedicated to e.c. and their twists, but maybe this gets close: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.01863.pdf.

Comment: But then, in step 2, we are still sampling over $E(\mathbb F_{p^2})-E(\mathbb F_p)$, how is that related to $E'(\mathbb F_p)$ when they are only guaranteed to have the same abscissa?

Comment: Is it actually the case that $\tilde E:=\{(x,y)\in E(\mathbb F_p):x\in\mathbb F_p, y\not\in\mathbb F_p\}$ being mapped to exactly $E'(\mathbb F_p)$, i.e.
$$
\iota(\tilde E)=E'(\mathbb F_p)?
$$

Comment: Well, the map $ι$ maps $(x,y)$ to $(-x,iy)$, so you answered your own question. But this fact is unimportant here, it is just a useful optimization trick. If you sample a point $P∈E[π+1]$, be it over $_p$ or over $_{p^2}$, and then you compute $Q=cP$, then $Q$ is still in $E[π+1]$, necessarily.

Comment: I think I didn't make myself clear. I was actually thinking why is step 2 sampling a point $P\in E[\pi+1]$. My explanation would be something like: because if $\sqrt{f(x)}$ does not falls in $\mathbb F_p$ then $\iota(P)\in E'(\mathbb F_p)$ thus $P\in E[\pi+1]$.

Comment: Thanks so much. Indeed it's a great surprise that the original CSIDH author jumps in and answered my questions.

Comment: Oh, that's what you were asking! I edited the answer, hopefully that point is clearer now. Basically, the answer is "Galois theory of $_p$", but since we're talking about finite fields you can make everything simple and explicit.

Comment: Btw, I'm not an "original CSIDH author". What is true is that CSIDH was inspired by an earlier work of Kieffer, Smith, and myself, where we explained how to apply the tricks above to isogeny based crypto. But I'm glad to be of help.